# CMake error while configuring llvm14.0.6 source code on Windows-10

Tags: cmake, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, llvm

When I configuring llvm14.0.6 source code on windows-10 using CMake-gui(3.25.0) and the generator is visual studio 16 2019, I got a CMake error as follow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZSGc.png)

I used the default configures except the "where is the source code" and "where to build the binaries" text boxes.

I don't know why I got this CMake error, can anybody help me?

I checked the CMakeList.txt which the error message indicated, and it shows like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z81am.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAi3v.png)
I don't what it means and how to solve this problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages using **images** for represent **text**. Instead, paste the **error message** directly into the question post as **text**. See [ask] and [that question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) on meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find an answer on github. Please refer to [CMake Error at cmake/modules/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/53281). In concise, when compiling llvm 14.0.6, we cannot use the source code on github directly. We must download the release package and copy the cmake resources to our project.